# Notation for a relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, relations

I'm reading up on "Set Theory and Logic" by Stoll and came upon notation for relations that I haven't seen before.  I've seen $x\sim{y},$ and $xRy$ before but Stoll uses this one.
$$(x,y)\in{\rho}$$
Now I admit that the prior two are specifically binary relations and I haven't seen ternary or n-ary relations like that.  Is the advantage of Stoll's notation apparent through n-ary relations?  An example of the ternary relational notation would be
$$(3,5,8)\in{+}$$ where $+$ is addition.  Or is this notation not really used?  As I mentioned I don't recall seeing this written before but I was curious about its popularity

Comment: I'd say the advantage of that notation is that *you are constantly reminded of what a relation IS* (viz. a subset of S x S, for some set S). The elements **are** order pairs.

Comment: I agree with you.  I thought it was easier to see that as well but I'm surprised I've never seen it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Formally a relation from a set $X$ to a set $Y$ is a subset of $X\times Y$; if I call this subset $\rho$, the familiar notation $x\mathbin{\rho}y$ is an abbreviation for the more formal $\langle x,y\rangle\in\rho$. Since the most familiar binary relations are typically written with this infix notation (e.g., $x\le y$, $A\supseteq B$, etc.), the more informal $x\mathbin{\rho}y$ is often felt to be more intuitive, but it does obscure the set-theoretic nature of relations a bit.

In short, Stoll’s notation is entirely standard, and you’re likely to encounter it any time you have to deal with relations in the abstract rather than with specific relations.

Actually, $+$ on, say, the integers is a function from $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z$ to $\Bbb Z$. Functions are just a special kind of relation, so it’s a relation from $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z$ to $\Bbb Z$ and therefore a subset of $(\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z)\times\Bbb Z$; formally one would write $\big\langle\langle 3,5\rangle,8\big\rangle\in+$, though there is a natural correspondence between $(\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z)\times\Bbb Z$ and the set of ordered triples of integers.

Comment: I've only had the basic intro to set theory that every undergraduate gets in Discrete and Abstract/Analysis but this is my first attempt at Set Theory as a field of study.  Do you recommend Stoll's book or is there a better one out there?

Comment: @Christopher: You could do a lot worse for an introduction, though as I recall elementary set theory is just part of Bob’s book. If you already have the book available, I’d use it as a starter and then move up to [this](http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Edition-Revised-Expanded-Mathematics/dp/0824779150), which is excellent and will take you *much* further into set theory proper.

Answer (score 3):

Relations are represented by sets of ordered pairs; so the advantage of this notation agrees with that representation.  In practice it is not all that common - certainly outside of set theory you almost always see infix notation for binary relations. For ternary and higher order relations this gets less practical (I can't think of a single example of "infix-like" notation in a ternary relation right now) and you're more likely to see $R(x,y,z)$ or $(x,y,z) \in R$.

Comment: I agree with you as well.  I tried to think of the infix notation for at least ternary and I drew a blank.  I like the notation but suppose it's in it's home in set theory.